# Ag-grid Vuejs it's possible to expand my tree to the top

Tags: vuejs2, ag-grid, expand

I want to know, if is posssible to expand my child from the top ? 
Thank,

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit. Have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @user2653663 [Exemple](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/36/1/1535974845-exemple.png)